# Is it possible for CloudFront to cache REST API calls

Tags: caching, amazon-cloudfront

I have a Single Page Application, and would like to cache some of the public REST API calls. Is it possible to use CloudFront to cache the JSON result of those API calls?

Comment: Are these APIs you manage/control? If so, yes, you can most likely place cloudfront in front of them and cache the responses.  CF just added expanded verb support so they can accept PUT,PATCH, and DELETE requests now.

Comment: Yes, it is simple rest services I control. I just can't find any documentation on how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can point api.yourdomain.com to cloudfront domain. Cloudfront will cache the json response based on your cache control headers.

However, you'll likely have to deal with cross domain issue if your single page app is not served from api.yourdomain.com. Cloudfront supports OPTIONS request which means it should be able to support CORS. You can also enable caching of OPTIONS requests.

http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/faqs/#Does_Amazon_CloudFront_cache_POST_responses

Comment: As of today, CloudFront does allow you to cache OPTION responses, as stated on the link you provided, "You may enable caching for the responses to OPTIONS requests."

Comment: It seems the link posted in answer is now valid anymore. Is there an updated link for this? Thanks.